# Unable to install or uninstall any package using apt-get due to insserv errors

Tags: apt, package-management

When ever I am trying to install or uninstall any package in Ubuntu 16.04 I get the following error:

```
insserv: warning: script 'K02cups' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'cups' missing LSB tags and overrides
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'mongod' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `mongod'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `mongod'
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: There is a loop between service smbd and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 3
insserv: There is a loop between service cups and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service smbd and cups if started
insserv:  loop involving service cups at depth 6
insserv:  loop involving service smbd at depth 5
insserv:  loop involving service cgproxy at depth 2
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service smbd and cups if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting cups depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I cannot seem to sort this out, any help or insights regarding this would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289667/unable-to-install-anything-using-apt-get-because-of-insserv

Comment: [Here's my `/etc/init.d/cups` for reference](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25195505/)

Comment: Thanks, I deleted my cups file from init.d, and it worked, my cups file was missing those LSB tags.